# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED react.js + axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to build log in pages for my react website. and then an error pops up when I trying to POST my data and see whether or not my Username and password will appear on the console.log text box. it is my localhost problem? because when I run my website in vscode. the localhost is 3000 but I do `axios.post('http://localhost:8000/login', data)` I am not sure if this is the one that costs the problem.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Button } from './Button';
import './login.css';



export default class Login extends Component{

    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = {
            username: this.user,
            password: this.pass,
        };
        
        
        axios.post('http://localhost:8000/login', data).then(
            res => {
                console.log(res);
            }
        ).catch(

            err => {
                console.log(err);
            }
        )
    };

    
    render(){
        return(
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="auth-container">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <h1>Log In</h1>
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input type="text" className="usernameText" placeholder="Username" onChange={e => this.user = e.target.value} />

                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" className="passwordText" placeholder="Password"  onChange={e => this.pass = e.target.value} />
                        

                    </div>

                    <Button className='btn--login' buttonSize='btn--wide' buttonColor='blue'>Log In</Button>
                    
            </div>
        
        
        </form>
        )
    }
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import "./App.css"
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { Switch, Route} from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/pages/HomePage/Home'
import Footer from './components/pages/Footer/Footer';
import Service from './components/Service';

import Info from './components/pages/Info/Info';
import infoMs from './components/pages/Info/infoMs';
import Login from './components/login';



function App()
{
  return(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home}/>
        <Route path='/service' exact component={Service}/>
        <Route path='/phua' component={Info}/>
        <Route path='/foong' component={infoMs}/>
        <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>


      </Switch>
      
      <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}


 

export default App;
```

here is the error in my broswer
[image]

Comment: Hi, It looks like there is nothing running on http://localhost:8000/login, this should be an API endpoint. please open a new tab in your browser and check if you get any response on http://localhost:8000/login. If not that means that your API endpoint is not running.

Comment: @BobSingor there is nothing when i run on  localhost:8000/login. but even though i put  localhost:8000/login on axios post. i still manage to visit the website on  localhost:3000/login